# Why receive event as arg in callback when event object works regardless?

Tags: javascript

I know this probably sounds duplicatish, but I've looked everywhere on stack and elsewhere and haven't found a clear explanation.

I get what the event object is, and why it's 'passed' as an argument to your DOM event callback function. What I realized recently however is that regardless of whether I pass e to my callback function, I can call the event object and get the same exact results. So this click event callback function:

```
function notfunky(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e.target);
}
```

Gives same result as:

```
function funky() { 
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event.target);
}
```

Every post I've read states that when you need access to the event object, you must receive it in the callback function...

The only difference I could find is that all the event methods (preventDefault etc) exist a bit further down the prototype chain.

Comment: unit testing. clairity. etc.

Comment: Ohhh, if I'd realized it was browser specific, I would have found the answer for this no prob. Thanks